# S3DISDataset in pointnet, I don't understand some of the code, so I want to know what it does in S3DISDataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, point-clouds

The source code in https://github.com/yanx27/Pointnet_Pointnet2_pytorch

```
class S3DISDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, split='train', data_root='trainval_fullarea',
                 num_point=4096, test_area=5, block_size=1.0, sample_rate=1.0, transform=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_point = num_point    # 采样点数
        self.block_size = block_size  # 将采样房间变为的大小
        self.transform = transform
        rooms = sorted(os.listdir(data_root))
        rooms = [room for room in rooms if 'Area_' in room]

        if split == 'train':
            rooms_split = [room for room in rooms if not 'Area_{}'.format(test_area) in room]   # ['Area_1_WC_1.txt','Area_1_conferenceRoom_1.txt',...]
        else:
            rooms_split = [room for room in rooms if 'Area_{}'.format(test_area) in room]     # ['Area_5_WC_1.txt', 'Area_5_WC_2.txt',...]

        self.room_points, self.room_labels = [], []        # 点云数据，点云目标值
        self.room_coord_min, self.room_coord_max = [], []  # 最小坐标，最大坐标
        num_point_all = []
        labelweights = np.zeros(13)     # array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

        for room_name in tqdm(rooms_split, total=len(rooms_split)):
            room_path = os.path.join(data_root, room_name)
            room_data = np.load(room_path)  # xyzrgbl, N*7
            points, labels = room_data[:, 0:6], room_data[:, 6]  # xyzrgb, N*6; l, N
            tmp, _ = np.histogram(labels, range(14))
            labelweights += tmp
            coord_min, coord_max = np.amin(points, axis=0)[:3], np.amax(points, axis=0)[:3]
            self.room_points.append(points), self.room_labels.append(labels)
            self.room_coord_min.append(coord_min), self.room_coord_max.append(coord_max)
            num_point_all.append(labels.size)
        labelweights = labelweights.astype(np.float32)
        labelweights = labelweights / np.sum(labelweights)
        self.labelweights = np.power(np.amax(labelweights) / labelweights, 1 / 3.0)
        print(self.labelweights)
        sample_prob = num_point_all / np.sum(num_point_all)
        num_iter = int(np.sum(num_point_all) * sample_rate / num_point)
        room_idxs = []
        for index in range(len(rooms_split)):
            room_idxs.extend([index] * int(round(sample_prob[index] * num_iter)))
        self.room_idxs = np.array(room_idxs)
        print("Totally {} samples in {} set.".format(len(self.room_idxs), split))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        room_idx = self.room_idxs[idx]
        points = self.room_points[room_idx]   # N * 6
        labels = self.room_labels[room_idx]   # N
        N_points = points.shape[0]

        while (True):
            center = points[np.random.choice(N_points)][:3]
            block_min = center - [self.block_size / 2.0, self.block_size / 2.0, 0]
            block_max = center + [self.block_size / 2.0, self.block_size / 2.0, 0]
            point_idxs = np.where((points[:, 0] >= block_min[0]) & (points[:, 0] <= block_max[0]) & (points[:, 1] >= block_min[1]) & (points[:, 1] <= block_max[1]))[0]
            if point_idxs.size > 1024:
                break

        if point_idxs.size >= self.num_point:
            selected_point_idxs = np.random.choice(point_idxs, self.num_point, replace=False)
        else:
            selected_point_idxs = np.random.choice(point_idxs, self.num_point, replace=True)

        # normalize
        selected_points = points[selected_point_idxs, :]  # num_point * 6
        current_points = np.zeros((self.num_point, 9))  # num_point * 9
        current_points[:, 6] = selected_points[:, 0] / self.room_coord_max[room_idx][0]
        current_points[:, 7] = selected_points[:, 1] / self.room_coord_max[room_idx][1]
        current_points[:, 8] = selected_points[:, 2] / self.room_coord_max[room_idx][2]
        selected_points[:, 0] = selected_points[:, 0] - center[0]
        selected_points[:, 1] = selected_points[:, 1] - center[1]
        selected_points[:, 3:6] /= 255.0
        current_points[:, 0:6] = selected_points
        current_labels = labels[selected_point_idxs]
        if self.transform is not None:
            current_points, current_labels = self.transform(current_points, current_labels)
        return current_points, current_labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.room_idxs)
```

The above is getting S3DIS dataset code, but I can't understand some code.

The following code is the part I don't understand.I want to know what it does.

I can't understand the meaning of `labelweights`, and I don't understand the last line of the code.

```
labelweights = labelweights.astype(np.float32)
labelweights = labelweights / np.sum(labelweights)
self.labelweights = np.power(np.amax(labelweights) / labelweights, 1 / 3.0)
```

I don't understand the following code. I want to know what each line of code means.

```
sample_prob = num_point_all / np.sum(num_point_all)
num_iter = int(np.sum(num_point_all) * sample_rate / num_point)
room_idxs = []
for index in range(len(rooms_split)):
room_idxs.extend([index] * int(round(sample_prob[index] * num_iter)))
self.room_idxs = np.array(room_idxs)
```

Can you explain the code to me?
Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the article, and I suggest you delve into it, hopefully, getting more details. Given that, that's what I understand from the code.

```py
self.labelweights = np.power(np.amax(labelweights) / labelweights, 1 / 3.0)
```

Before the assignment labelweights contains a probability distribution. The `labelweights` array is then normalized by the max probability and then inverted (`np.amax(labelweights) / labelweights`). Finally, the cubic root is applied those inverted ratios.

In summary, if `p` is a probability distribution, the line computes `cubic_root((p / max(p)) ^ {-1})`.

Given the name, this variable is probably used to sample observations based on their class frequency, by assigning more weights to the less represented classes and the cubic root someway flattens the weights to make them less variable.

```py
sample_prob = num_point_all / np.sum(num_point_all)
num_iter = int(np.sum(num_point_all) * sample_rate / num_point)
room_idxs = []
for index in range(len(rooms_split)):
    room_idxs.extend([index] * int(round(sample_prob[index] * num_iter)))
self.room_idxs = np.array(room_idxs)
```

`sample_prob` is a probability distribution containing the frequency of point in each room.

`num_iter` is obtained as a percentage `sample_rate` of the total number of points in all the rooms (`np.sum(num_point_all)`). Such percentage is divided by  `num_point` to obtain, perhaps, a total number of batches or something similar.

`room_idxs` is created by joining several `list`s together (`[el] * n` generate a `list` containing `n` times the `el` element)).

Each of these `list`s contain the same room index replicated `sample_prob[index] * num_iter` times (therefore `len(room_idxs)` is `num_iter` ca.).

In summary, this code is meant to sample a room index based on the number of points it contains.